# Ipython option not visible in spyder

Tags: ipython, spyder

I just installed the macports versions of spyder and ipython onto my macbook pro running osx 10.8. There does not seem to be a way to open an ipython console from this version of spyder.  That is, there is no mention of ipython in the Interpreters menu, nor in the preferences.

Has someone come across this problem and might know how to fix it?  Many thanks.

Adrian

Comment: Check the IPython version (`?` > Optional Dependencies), then open an IPython console through View > Windows and Toolbars.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder dev here*) According to [this](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=ipython) page the latest stable IPython version in MacPorts is 1.0, which is unsupported by Spyder 2.2.3 (our latest stable release).

We are working right now to make it compatible for our next release (i.e. 2.2.4), which will be available in two weeks.