# IPython not available in Spyder

Tags: ipython, spyder

I don't think I'm suffering from the problem in [this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438538/ipython-option-not-visible-in-spyder).

I'm running [Linux Mint 16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_Mint_releases) (based on Ubuntu 13.10) and have Spyder 2.2.5 and IPython 0.13.2.

Under the `Interpreters` menu I only see `Open a Python interpreter...` and not an option to open an IPython interpreter.

Is there anything I have to do to "show" Spyder where IPython "is"?

Here is the output of my "Optional Dependencies":

```
IPython >=0.13  :  0.13.2 (OK)
matplotlib >=1.0:  1.2.1 (OK)
pep8 >=0.6      :  None (NOK)
pyflakes >=0.5.0:  0.7.3 (OK)
pylint >=0.25   :  None (NOK)
rope >=0.9.2    :  0.9.2 (OK)
sphinx >=0.6.6  :  1.1.3 (OK)
```

Comment: What is reported for the IPython entry in the `? > Optional Dependencies` menu entry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In principle you should be able to open an IPython console with `View` -> `Windows` -> `IPython console`... do you have this?
If this is not an option, try this: from an interpreter window,

```
import IPython
IPython.start_ipython()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The command starts IPython in the Spyder interpreter window. But still no option under `View` -> `Windows` -> `IPython`.

Comment: Necessary option is under `View`->`Panes`->`IPython console` in Spyder 2.7.8 and 3.1.4 for people in the future.

Answer (score 14):

For me, the IPython console was not available anymore in Spyder (2.3.8) after updating IPython to version 4.1.1.

The solution was to install/upgrade qtconsole:

```
pip install -U qtconsole
```

See also https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2608#issuecomment-130586847

Answer (score 9):

In my case (`Spyder3.0.0dev`), I checked:

`Help -> Optional dependencies`

and saw that my `IPython` was outdated. So shut Spyder and I upgraded `ipython`,

```
sudo pip3 install ipython --upgrade
```

or if you use Python2:

```
sudo pip install ipython --upgrade
```

and restarted Spyder. Voila! `IPython` console is there

Comment: Lots of nice information in that optional dependencies menu. `pip install`ing all of the missing ones worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue and in this case I missed the ipython-qtconsole package.
On my Mint OS :

```
sudo apt-get install ipython-qtconsole
```

did the trick.

I found the info there https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html after having tried the proposed solutions of this post

Answer (score 3):

For python 3, following resolved the issue for me on Mint OS

```
sudo apt-get install ipython3-qtconsole
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo pip3 install ipython --upgrade
sudo pip3 install qtconsole --upgrade
```

With this it's done and working!

Answer (score 1):

For me on `Sypder 3.7` this worked:

`Consoles`->`Restart Kernal` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>)

then:

`Consoles` -> `Open an IPython console` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

Coming over from Windows 10 to Linux Mint still more comfortable with the Software Manager, installed Spyder3, Ipython, Python-tk, and Ipython3-qtconsole, don't know if Ipython or Python-tk where necessary.  Spyder3 now has a "Open IPython console" drop down under Consoles.