# Spyder 2.3.4 + Python 3.4: IPython not available

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

I have just installed Spyder 2.3.4. on my Ubuntu 14.04 x64 machine. In former versions I was working with Python 2.7 and had the option to start an IPython shell on the startup. But I can't find this option in the newest version anymore.

At first, I thought my question is related to the question
[IPython not available in Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936277/ipython-not-available-in-spyder) but "sympy" and "ipython" are installed correctly:

```
cord@laptop:~$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade ipython
Requirement already up-to-date: ipython in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist- packages
Cleaning up...
cord@laptop:~$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade sympy
Requirement already up-to-date: sympy in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
cord@laptop:~$
```

Does anyone have an idea why it is not working?

Cheers
Cord

Comment: Btw, IPython is working:

   >>> import IPython
   >>> IPython.start_ipython()
   Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
   Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   
   IPython 3.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
   ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install ipython3-qtconsole
```

should fix the problem. Before, I only had the regular ipython package installed..